# How to plot different groups of data from a dataframe into a single figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a temperature file with many years of *temperature* records in the format below:

```
2012-04-12,16:13:09,20.6
2012-04-12,17:13:09,20.9
2012-04-12,18:13:09,20.6
2007-05-12,19:13:09,5.4
2007-05-12,20:13:09,20.6
2007-05-12,20:13:09,20.6
2005-08-11,11:13:09,20.6
2005-08-11,11:13:09,17.5
2005-08-13,07:13:09,20.6
2006-04-13,01:13:09,20.6
```

Every year has different numbers of time of records, so the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) `datetimeindices` are all different.

I want to plot the different year's data in the same figure for comparison:

- The X-axis is `datetimeindices` from Jan to Dec
- The Y-axis is the *temperature*

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- Chang's answer shows how to plot a different DataFrame on the same `axes`.
- In this case, all of the data is in the same dataframe, so it's better to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

  - Alternatively, [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) can be used.
  - `dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Year', values='value', aggfunc='mean')`
- When using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), `names=` creates column headers when there are none in the file. The `'date'` column must be parsed into `datetime64[ns] Dtype` so the [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) extractor can be used to extract the `month` and `year`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# given the data in a file as shown in the op
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', names=['date', 'time', 'value'], parse_dates=['date'])
    
# create additional month and year columns for convenience
df['Year'] = df.date.dt.year
df['Month'] = df.date.dt.month

# groupby the month a year and aggreate mean on the value column
dfg = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['value'].mean().unstack()

# display(dfg)                     
Year        2005  2006       2007  2012
Month                                  
4            NaN  20.6        NaN  20.7
5            NaN   NaN  15.533333   NaN
8      19.566667   NaN        NaN   NaN
```

Now it's easy to plot each year as a separate line. The OP only has one observation for each year, so only a marker is displayed.

```py
ax = dfg.plot(figsize=(9, 7), marker='.', xticks=dfg.index)
```

[image]

Answer (score 408):

Try:

```
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 42):

If you a running Jupyter/Ipython notebook and having problems using;

`ax = df1.plot()`

`df2.plot(ax=ax)`

Run the command inside of the same cell!! It wont, for some reason, work when they are separated into sequential cells. For me at least.

Answer (score 6):

To do this for multiple dataframes, you can do a for loop over them:

```
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 8))
ax = dict_of_dfs['FOO'].column.plot()
for BAR in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    if BAR == 'FOO':
        pass
    else:
        dict_of_dfs[BAR].column.plot(ax=ax)
```

---

This can also be implemented without the `if` condition:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for BAR in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    dict_of_dfs[BAR].plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `hue` parameter in `seaborn`. For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')

     year month  passengers
0    1949   Jan         112
1    1949   Feb         118
2    1949   Mar         132
3    1949   Apr         129
4    1949   May         121
..    ...   ...         ...
139  1960   Aug         606
140  1960   Sep         508
141  1960   Oct         461
142  1960   Nov         390
143  1960   Dec         432

sns.lineplot(x='month', y='passengers', hue='year', data=df)
```

[image]