# Subplot Stacked Bar Graphs

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, bar-chart, subplot, stacked-chart

I've got three stacked bar graphs which I have gotten to display correctly but I want to display them side by side (as opposed to three different graphs (one under the other)).

Current code that display three graphs individually is (where axX_Group are the dataframes that have my data in them).

```
ax1_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,15), title='Makes and Years (Pre 2000)')
ax2_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Makes and Years (2000-2009)')
ax3_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Makes and Years (2010+)')
```

I know I have to use the subplot function to plot the graphs on one figure but can't seem to figure out how to assign the current graphs properly.

My main problem is that all of the examples I've come across online use subplot function to assign the location of the graph (which I understand) but then plot the graphs as a function of X and Y - as follows:

```
 figure = plt.figure()
 ax1 = figure.add_subplot(311)
 ax2 = figure.add_subplot(312)
 ax3 = figure.add_subplot(313)

 ax1.plot(x1,y1)
 ax2.plot(x2,y2)
 ax3.plot(x3,y3)
```

I need to figure out how to use the ax1.plot(X, Y) portion such that I can call the .plot(stacked bar chart)

```
    ax1_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,15), title='Makes and Years (Pre 2000)')
```

So I've gotten to this but it's not working:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1_Group = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax2_Group = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax3_Group = fig.add_subplot(133)
ax1_Group.plot(ax1_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,15), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (Pre 2000)'))
ax2_Group.plot(ax2_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (2000-2009)'))
ax3_Group.plot(ax3_Group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (2010+)'))
```

I've tried numerous things and can't quite get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does adding keyword `subplots=True` do what you want (as http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#subplots)? If not, any chance you could include a sketch of exactly what you want? Also, as you say dataframe, I assume you are using Pandas? Worth adding as a tag. Worst case you could extract data with something like `x1, y1 = ax1_Group.values` and plot as in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax1_Group.plot(ax1_Group.plot(ax = ax1, kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,15), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (Pre 2000)'))

ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax2_Group.plot(ax2_Group.plot(ax = ax2, kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (2000-2009)'))

ax3 = plt.subplot(133)
ax3_Group.plot(ax3_Group.plot(ax = ax3, kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(6,20), title='Breakdown of Makes and Years (2010+)'))
```

Comment: Please explain the *following code* for OP and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your problem is as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872533/plot-different-dataframes-in-the-same-figure), basically,

```
ax = ax1_Group.plot(kind='barh', 
                    stacked=True, 
                    figsize=(6,15), 
                    title='Makes and Years (Pre 2000)')
ax2_Group.plot(ax=ax, 
               kind='barh', 
               stacked=True, 
               title='Makes and Years (2000-2009)')
ax3_Group.plot(ax=ax, 
               kind='barh', 
               stacked=True, 
               title='Makes and Years (2010+)')
```