# in pandas , add scatter plot to line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to add a scatter plot to a line plot by using plandas plot function (in jupyter notebook).

I have tried the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# plot the line 
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,2,6,4]})
ax = a.plot.line()

# try to add the scatterplot
b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [5, 2]})
plot = b.reset_index().plot.scatter(x = 'index', y = 'b', c ='r', ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

I also checked the following various SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872533/plot-different-dataframes-in-the-same-figure) but couldn't find the solution.

If anytone can help me, that ould be very appreciated.

---

EDIT:

somehow the accepted answers works, but i realise that in my case the reason it was not working might have to do with the fact i was using datetime.

like in this code, i cant see the red dots...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot the line 
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,2,6,4]}, index = pd.date_range(dt(2019,1,1), periods = 4))
plot = a.plot.line(ax = ax)

# try to add the scatterplot
b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [5, 2]}, index = [x.timestamp() for x in pd.date_range(dt(2019,1,1), periods = 2)])
plot = b.reset_index().plot.scatter(x = 'index', y = 'b', c ='r', ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: set up your ax first. And use the `ax=ax` in both plot calls

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: @user1558604 Thx a lot. Could you give me the 2 or 3 lines of code that entails ? I find it confusing.

Comment: @jim , can you please explain the difference between the expected behavior and the wanted behavior?

Comment: @Quang Hoang well (in jupyter notebook) it simply doesnt show the plot with the line and scatter..

Comment: It does in my notebook :-).

Comment: It works in my notebook too. I'm assuming there is some other plot in the notebook.

Comment: true it does work... Sorry guys im confused..

Comment: @Elegant Code you mean if a plot already exists it wouldnt work ? Its a long time i havent used matplotlib...

Comment: @jimbasquiat, I believe that because of the magic Jupyter does behind the scenes, if you already have a plot set up previously, your new calls to df.plot() may or may not, add to the plot you're expecting to add to, unless you are explicit about which axes to add to, as user1558604 mentioned. I'm writing it into ans wer now.

Comment: @Elegant Code thx very appreciated

Comment: @ElegantCode answer was what I was referring to jim.  I have just submitted an edit (which you probably can't see yet) which will fix the overwritten ax issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (just add `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` in the beginning):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot the line 
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,2,6,4]})
a.plot.line(ax=ax)

# try to add the scatterplot
b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [5, 2]})
plot = b.reset_index().plot.scatter(x = 'index', y = 'b', c ='r', ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: Please let me know if you need anymore help.]

**Edit:**
This will work for datetimes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
# %matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot the line 
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,2,6,4]}, index = pd.date_range(dt(2019,1,1), periods = 4))
plot = plt.plot_date(x=a.reset_index()['index'], y=a['a'], fmt="-")

# try to add the scatterplot
b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [5, 2]}, index = pd.date_range(dt(2019,1,1), periods = 2))
plot = plt.scatter(x=b.reset_index()['index'], y=b['b'], c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thax, but then is it not overwritten by `ax = a.plot.line()` ?

Comment: @jimbasquiat, ooopppsss, sorry about that. I changed it in my Jupyter notebook code but then I only copied the one line and added it to yours, instead of the whole code with the additional change user1558604 made. I initially copied your code into the answer and already indented it, and didn't want to have to reindent it again. Silly mistake. I'm glad user1558604 and you caught it quickly.

Comment: @Elegant Code if you still have a bit of time, could you look at my edit ? (cant seem to find the issue when i use datetime on the x axis...)

Comment: @jimbasquiat ,added support for datetime